# Prove the following set identity: (A ∩ B) \ (B ∩ C) = A ∩ (B \ C)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here's what I did:

Let x ∈ (A ∩ B) \ (B ∩ C):

Given (A ∩ B) \ (B ∩ C) we can say:

> (x ∈ A and x ∈ B) and $\neg$(x ∈ B and x ∈ C)

> (x ∈ A and x ∈ B) and (x ∉ B or x ∉ C)   (Here's where I'm stuck)

How exactly do I expand these brackets?

Comment: Hi! Just one thing, the line $x\notin (x\in$… doesn’t make sense. You should use the negation symbol in front of the parenthesis, “$\neg$“,  that can be written using \neg.

Comment: Distributive law gives (A and  B and not B) or (A and B and not C). The first part has a contradiction, so you get (A and (B and not C)) which is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(A\cap B)\setminus (B\cap C)=(A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C)'=$$ $$=(A\cap B)\cap(B'\cup C')=$$ $$=(A\cap B \cap B')\cup (A\cap B \cap C')=$$ $$=(A\cap \emptyset)\cup (A\cap (B \setminus C))=$$ $$=\emptyset\cup (A\cap (B \setminus C))=$$ $$=A\cap (B \setminus C).$$

Comment: +1. My edit was for visual style; in particular to not have a formula go over the end of  a line, and with the modern style that an $=$ or other relation symbol at the end of a line is repeated at the start of the next line.... & I added a period at the end.

Answer (score 2):

These are all equivalent steps:

$(x\in A$ and $x\in B)$ and $(x\notin B$ or $x\notin C)$

$x\in A$ and $\big(x\in B$ and $(x\notin B$ or $x\notin C)\big)$

$x\in A$ and $\big((x\in B$ and $x\notin B$) or ($x\in B$ and $x\notin C)\big)$

$x\in A$ and $\big(x\in B$ and $x\notin C\big)$

$x\in A\cap(B\setminus C)$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your last line, you can distinguish 2 cases:

Case 1: $x\notin B$. Then, $x=\emptyset$ which is part of every set.

Case 2: $x\notin C$ but $x\in B$. Then, certainly, $x\in B \setminus C$. But since $x \in A$, we have that indeed that $x\in A\cap (B \setminus C)$